# Faster RCNN for TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, detection, caffe, pycaffe

Has anyone implement the FRCNN for TensorFlow version?
I found some related repos as following:

1. [Implement roi pool layer](https://github.com/yuxng/tensorflow)
2. [Implement fast RCNN based on py-faster-rcnn repo](https://github.com/ExonRen/tf-fast-rcnn)

but for 1: assume the roi pooling layer works (I haven't tried), and there are something need to be implemented as following:

- ROI data layer e.g. [roidb](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/lib/roi_data_layer/roidb.py).
- Linear Regression e.g. [SmoothL1Loss](https://github.com/rbgirshick/caffe-fast-rcnn/blob/0dcd397b29507b8314e252e850518c5695efbb83/src/caffe/layers/smooth_L1_loss_layer.cu)
- ROI pool layer post-processing for end-to-end training which should convert the ROI pooling layer's results to feed into CNN for classifier.

For 2: em...., it seems based on py-faster-rcnn which based on Caffe to prepared pre-processing (e.g. roidb) and feed data into Tensorflow to train the model, it seems weird, so I may not tried it.

So what I want to know is that, will [Tensorflow support Faster RCNN in the future](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/739)?. If not, do I have any mis-understand which mentioned above? or has any repo or someone support that?

Comment: SmoothL1Loss should be relatively easy to implement using the actual tf for ROI pooling no idea...

Comment: I am working on the similar target of your question. I found that it hard to represent dynamic bboxes in tensor. That maybe the reason why the method 2 you mentioned use caffe to pre-process data. I am trying to figure out whether there is some other way to achieve that in TensorFlow.

Comment: How about [this implementation](https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF)?

Answer (score 16):

Tensorflow has just released an official Object Detection API [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection), that can be used for instance with their various slim [models](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets).

This API contains implementation of various Pipelines for Object Detection, including popular Faster RCNN, with their pre-trained models as well.

Comment: to all mods/reviewers: please do **NOT** delete this answer as "link only": the nature of the question permits such answers and this particular one is okay.

Comment: Links seem dead

Comment: I've fixed them